# No suitable driver found for jJDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

I am getting this exception

No suitable driver found for

```
jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Test [saad on SAAD]
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Test [saad on SAAD]");
```

Answer (score 1):

Before this

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Test [saad on SAAD]", dbusername, dbpassword);  // default username = "root" , default password = ""
```

You have to write this

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
```

But first of all, you must import the driver jar for apache derby